# Seeking tool to convert MapInfo WOR to QGIS project file with symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, mapinfo, qgs

Is there a tool to convert MapInfo WOR to QGIS project file with symbology?

It should be possible to create one as both WOR/QGS are text based.

Comment: If you know the rendering order of the layers in your .WOR you can just open the .tab files in the new version QGIS 3.20 Odense. There is a new feature in QGIS 3.20 Odense - Embedded Styling  https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-new-embedded-styling-renderer-with-ogr-feature-styles-support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a plugin named OpenWOR. You need to search for the plugin in the plugin manager. The plugin is experimental, so in order to find it, you should go to `Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> Settings -> Check the "Show experimental plugins"`. Then you should find OpenWOR Plugin.

Comment: Just found this old question of mine again... btw this is now in a new repo and is 2x only - all plugins from French Ministry of Ecology disappeared from QGIS main repository. Maybe something related to recent publication workflow changes? 

Anyway, the ministry has a dedicated repository here: 

http://piece-jointe-carto.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/NAT002/QGIS/plugins/plugins.xml (as per http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Open-MapInfo-Workspace-Plugin-td5273898.html)

Comment: OpenWOR is only for QGIS versions 2.x . A new version is needed.

Comment: @MaunoAho  If you know the rendering order of the layers in your .WOR you can just open the .tab files in QGIS 3.20 Odense. This version can display the MapInfo symbology of features.